# How to bind Syncfusion Grid via json result on ajax call

Tags: jquery, data-binding, syncfusion

I have a dropdown list, On change of that dropdown, doing the below ajax call from which I want to bind the syncfusion grid. JSON method is hitting and getting the list but I am unable to bind the data to grid.

```
$.post(
     "User/GetUserData/",
         { 'CategoryId': CategoryId },
         function (data) {
            // I want to bind the grid here
         });
```

I tried in 2 ways one is to return json result an other way returning the view

Option 1:

```
public JsonResult GetUserData(string CategoryId)
{
   return Json(model.lstUserModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Option 2:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult GetUserData(string CategoryId)
 {
   model.lstUserModel= GetUserData(Convert.Int32(CategoryId));
   return View("UserView", model);

 }
```

in both the option I am unable to bind the data to list.

Answer (score 2):

After you got data in ajax call then bind data to grid like below.

```
[HTML]
<div id="Grid"/> 

[Script]
$.post(
 "User/GetUserData/",
     { 'CategoryId': CategoryId },
     function (data) {
         $("#Grid").ejGrid({
            dataSource: data, // data must be array of json
        });
     });
```